# excel copy cell from a closed workbook.

Tags: excel, vbscript, excel-2007, xlm, vba

I am trying to Copy data from a cell in a closed workbook into another workbook without opening the original one.

the code i have show far... works but i need to be able to write the data to a certain cell on the open workbook.

```
Private Function GetValue(path, file, sheet, ref)
'   Retrieves a value from a closed workbook
    Dim arg As String
'   Make sure the file exists
    If Right(path, 1) <> "\" Then path = path & "\"
    If Dir(path & file) = "" Then
        GetValue = "File Not Found"
        Exit Function
    End If
'   Create the argument
    arg = "'" & path & "[" & file & "]" & sheet & "'!" & _
      Range(ref).Range("A1").Address(, , xlR1C1)
'   Execute an XLM macro
    GetValue = ExecuteExcel4Macro(arg)
End Function

Sub TestGetValue2()
    p = "F:\excel_Project"
    f = "Book1.xlsx"
    s = "Sheet1"
    a = "A1"
 GetValue(p, f, s, a) = ("A1")

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to set the value of a cell to whatever your `GetValue` function returns, you'd do the following

```
Range("A1") = GetValue(p, f, s, a)
```

However, you'll need to make sure that your destination (i.e. where you want to write `GetValue`) is the same size/dimension as `GetValue`. For example, if `GetValue` is a cell then the above will work as expected. However, if `GetValue` is a 1x2 range of cells and you use the above code, only `A1` will be populated with a value (the first value) from `GetValue`

Comment: + 1 For the extra info

Answer (score 0):

I was in need to retrieve a cell from a dynamic list of a closed file stored in a cell of a sheet.

Besides the loop, I tried to use Formula to solve my problem

this worked for me :

```
Range("A1").Formula ="='F:\excel_Project\[Book1.xlsb]Sheet1'!$A1"
```

In case anyone needs to do the same thing with a list of files...

```
Range("a" & index).Formula = "='f:\excel_project\[" & myname & ".xlsb]Sheet1'!$A1"
```